# Uploading to Google cloud storage signed url from client

Tags: google-cloud-storage

I have generated a signed url from the google cloud storage that works fine when I upload files via postman, but it is impossible to upload a file from the client. I have tried everything: fetch, axios, xmlRequest––you name it. Please help me out

```js
const files = Array.from(event.target.files)  
  const file:any = files[0]  
  const {data: {signedUrl}} = await axios.get('https://localhost:3000/signedUrlUpload')
  try {     
    const resp = await fetch(signedUrl, {
      method: 'PUT',
      body: file,
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'audio/wave'
      }      
    })
    console.log(resp);

  } catch (e) {
    console.error(e);
  }
```

Error: TypeError: Failed to fetch

Comment: When it doesn't work, what sort of error do you get? Could you paste an example request and error?

Comment: @BrandonYarbrough done!

Comment: Could you post the actual HTTP response? Well, I've got no idea why axios gives you "TypeError: Failed to fetch", but it's not very informative.